# Inner Products Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ with $\| x\|=1$ and $A,W\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ be invertible.

Can we show any inequality between $\frac{x^TWA^{-1}Wx}{||Wx||^2}$ and $\frac{x^TW^TA^{-1}Wx}{||Wx||^2}$?

Comment: Does the first expression really have no transposed W ?

Comment: Yes. This is the only difference.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $W=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$, $x=(1,1)$. Then $$x^TW^TA^{-1}Wx=3,\qquad x^TWA^{-1}Wx=0$$ So no inequality of the type $|x^TW^TA^{-1}Wx|\le c|x^TWA^{-1}Wx|$ (or interchanged) can hold between the two expressions in general.

Comment: $\| x \|=\sqrt{2}\neq 1$. But the counter example works for $x'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x$.